# How to joomla cron manually

Tags: joomla, cron

Using Joonla 3.7 I used to get a warning about the cron job not running because my provider does not allow me to run cron jobs.

I could run the cronjob manually by clicking on the warning message and all was fine to me.

After updating Joomla to 3.8.3 I cannot find the link to run the cron manually.

Can you please tell me if and how this can be done in the control-panel?

Comment: Please use [Joomla.SE] Stackexchange for general questions about Joomla.

Comment: Please use Joomla Stackexchange for general questions about Joomla

Comment: thank you for editing my dutch english :-);I found solution in civicrm plugin manage planned jobs; there's a manual update link over there